# Obtener la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Un saludo cordial, estoy elaborando una función para obtener la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento con TypeScript. La función contiene en la firma un paramento de entrada que es la fecha en formato **aaaa-MM-DD** y preciso que retorne la edad en años, meses y días.

Answer (score 2):

Una manera más corta de hacerlo sería usando el tipo de dato Date (que es la cantidad de milisegundos en una fecha)

Entonces los pasos serían:

- Transformar las dos fechas en el tipo `Date` (son milisegundos)
- Restar las 2 fechas (Obtener la cantidad de milisegundos entre las 2 fechas)
- Calcular la cantidad de días que son esos milisegundos.
- Calcular cuántos años son esos días (dividiendo días / 365.25)
- Calcular la cantidad de meses entre los días restantes
- Calcular la cantidad de días entre los días restantes, de los días restantes)

El código:

```
function diffDate(date = '1900-01-01') {
  const date1 = new Date()
  const date2 = new Date(date)

  // Dias:
  const dayDefinition = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // Este número es: Milisegundos * segundos * minutos * horas
  const daysDiff = Math.ceil((Math.abs(date1 - date2)) / dayDefinition);

  const years = Math.floor(daysDiff / 365.25);
  const remainingDays = Math.floor(daysDiff - (years * 365.25));
  const months = Math.floor((remainingDays / 365.25) * 12);
  const days = Math.ceil(daysDiff - (years * 365.25 + (months / 12 * 365.25)));

  return `${years} año${years == 1 ? '' : 's'}, ${months} mes${months == 1 ? '' : 'es'}, ${days} dia${days == 1 ? '' : 's'}`
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Un saludo cordial.
La función se puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
 * Calculate age in years and months
 * @param birthDate
 * @returns
 */
export function getAgeYearMonth(birthDate: string) {
  /** VALIDATE */
  if (birthDate === null) {
    birthDate = '1900-01-01'
  }

  let dateValues = birthDate.split('-')
  let birthDateDay = Number(dateValues[2])
  let birthDateMonth = Number(dateValues[1])
  let birthDateYear = Number(dateValues[0])

  /** GET DATE NOW */
  let dateNow = new Date()
  let dateNowYear = dateNow.getFullYear()
  let dateNowMonth = dateNow.getMonth() + 1
  let dateNowDay = dateNow.getDate()

  /** AGE IS CALCULATED IN YEARS, MONTH AND DAY */
  let ageFull = dateNowYear - birthDateYear
  if (dateNowMonth < birthDateMonth) {
    ageFull--
  }
  if (birthDateMonth == dateNowMonth && dateNowDay < birthDateDay) {
    ageFull--
  }

  /** CALCULATE THE MOUNTAINS */
  let monthes = 0

  if (dateNowMonth > birthDateMonth && birthDateDay > dateNowDay)
    monthes = dateNowMonth - birthDateMonth - 1
  else if (dateNowMonth > birthDateMonth)
    monthes = dateNowMonth - birthDateMonth
  if (dateNowMonth < birthDateMonth && birthDateDay < dateNowDay)
    monthes = 12 - (birthDateMonth - dateNowMonth)
  else if (dateNowMonth < birthDateMonth)
    monthes = 12 - (birthDateMonth - dateNowMonth + 1)
  if (dateNowMonth == birthDateMonth && birthDateDay > dateNowDay) monthes = 11

  /** CALCULATE THE DAYS */
  let days = 0
  if (dateNowDay > birthDateDay) days = dateNowDay - birthDateDay
  if (dateNowDay < birthDateDay) {
    let ultimodaymonth = new Date(dateNowYear, dateNowMonth - 1, 0)
    days = ultimodaymonth.getDate() - (birthDateDay - dateNowDay)
  }

  return `${ageFull} año(s), ${monthes} mes(es), ${days} dia(s),`
}
```

Saludos.